# JQuery mobile returned from background event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

good time

I am wondering if there is any jquery mobile event that's trigger if the user returned back to app and it's was in the background and still alive not terminated !!!

So the app in the background and swapped back again, I want to trigger some events at this case.

any thoughts?

Comment: what tool do you use to build your app? Or it is a web-app?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and the correct event is "resume" below the code to run the event

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {

                    // post your action or any trigger here

                });
```